# XSL - check a mapping using key() against a list of items

Tags: xml, xslt, pseudocode

what I would like to achieve is a solution where an existing mapping in XSL is used to verify that a number of items are supported. Items to be tested are stored in an attribute (separated by whitespace).

```
<items>
  <item name="item1" supported="true">
  <item name="item2" supported="false">
  <item name="item3" supported="true">
</items>
```

We are using an additional XML file stating some test cases.

```
<testsuite name="suite1">
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test1">
      <required_item name="item1"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test2">
      <required_item name="item1"/>
      <required_item name="item2"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test3">
      <required_item name="item1"/>
      <required_item name="item3"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test4"></testcase>
  </testcases>
</testsuite>
```

**Question:** How could we achieve the following pseudo code?

```
FOREACH testcase
  IF "required_items" is EMPTY
  THEN
    print TEST_TO_RUN += testcase
  ELSE
    IF __ALL__ "required_items" are SUPPORTED
      print TEST_TO_RUN += testcase
    END IF
  END IF
END FOREACH
```

The expected result in a generated Makefile would look like this.

```
TEST_TO_RUN+= test1 test3 test4
```

Comment: **1.** The requirement is not quite clear - esp. with regard to "required_items". What if only *some* items are supported?  Please expand your example and post the expected result (as code) for each case. -- **2.** Multiple items in a single attribute = bad XML structure. Do you have any control over that? -- **3.** Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Yes I have control over it, because we own the XSD as well. :-) So would you recommend to add multiple elements instead?

Comment: "*So would you recommend to add multiple elements instead?*" Yes. Otherwise you'll have to tokenize.

Comment: Please post the expected result **and** answer my question #3 regarding your XSLT version.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following well-formed(!) test input:

**XML**

```
<items>
  <item name="item1" supported="true"/>
  <item name="item2" supported="true"/>
  <item name="item3" supported="false"/>
  <item name="item4" supported="false"/>
</items>
```

and an additional document:

**testsuite.xml**

```
<testsuite name="suite1">
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test1">
      <required_item name="item1"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test2">
      <required_item name="item1"/>
      <required_item name="item2"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test3">
      <required_item name="item2"/>
      <required_item name="item3"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test4">
      <required_item name="item3"/>
      <required_item name="item4"/>
    </testcase>
  </testcases>
  <testcases>
    <testcase name="test5"></testcase>
  </testcases>
</testsuite>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-testsuite" select="'testsuite.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-name" match="item" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>TEST_TO_RUN+= </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="document($path-to-testsuite)/testsuite/testcases/testcase[every $i in key('item-by-name', required_item/@name, current()) satisfies $i/@supported='true']/@name"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
TEST_TO_RUN+= test1 test2 test5
```

Comment: Would that solution work even in XSLT 1.0 (unfortunately we are not allowed to upgrade).

Comment: @Sebastian No, it will not work in XSLT 1.0. I asked you - twice - about your version, before posting my answer. I am afraid I have no more time to give to this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!